# CalDAV only works for first synchronisation, and then stops updateing the calender forever

Tags: iphone, data-synchronization, calendar, ssl, caldav

From the same server I can successfully sync cardDAVs contacts, and IMAPs-mail, so I've ruled out network issues.

Furthermore, that same installation also syncs many other users (non-i) -Devices Contacts, Calenders, and Mails, so I've ruled out [SOGOs](https://sogo.nu/) CalDAV implementation.

This Problem is not present on the WinPhones, [Androids(with DavDroid)](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=at.bitfire.davdroid), [Thunderbird/Lightning](http://sabre.io/dav/clients/thunderbird/), and even [Outlook 2010](https://sourceforge.net/projects/outlookcaldavsynchronizer/). I kind-of feel stupid now having recommended iDevices in the past.

I tried:

- Rebooting normally
- Signing out of iCloud, then rebooting
- Factory-reset, then configuring the CalDAV first, then the rest.
- Opened the non-SSL Port (shudder) to the outside world for testing.
- Creating the Calender "twice", Once as Calender, and once as Contactlist

None of those worked, and the last one was impossible through the settings dialog

I'm not quite sure, how to proceed. In the meantime, I bought some cheap androids, so that my users at least have their calendar on the road with them.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check in Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars > Fetch New Data > Fetch Every 15 minutes.

Maybe it is set to Manually.

Comment: No, set to 15 Minutes. My users have also attempted to manually update by "dragging down" from the calendar view.

Comment: What sync option do you have at https://sogo.nu/?

Comment: it's self-hosted, haven't seen options on first run-through, that would make it work everywhere but the iDevices. Its mostly running on (good, imho) defaults.

Comment: Take a look at the error logging or enable debug mode on your server